# Using Linq to transform objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects of this class:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert that list of DataPoints into a list of objects of this class:

```
public class ChartSeries
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<uint> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an explicit example of the list of DataPoints

```
IEnumerable<DataPoint> data = new List<DataPoint>() { 
    new DataPoint() { date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4), Items = new List<DataPoint.Item>() {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Pirates", total=90 } , {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Buccaneers", total=20 } }}}, 
    new DataPoint() { date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), Items = new List<DataPoint.Item>() {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Pirates", total=80 } , {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Buccaneers", total=19 } }}},
    new DataPoint() { date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2), Items = new List<DataPoint.Item>() {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Pirates", total=70 } , {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Buccaneers", total=18 } }}},
    new DataPoint() { date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Items = new List<DataPoint.Item>() {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Pirates", total=60 } , {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Buccaneers", total=17 } }}},
    new DataPoint() { date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-0), Items = new List<DataPoint.Item>() {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Pirates", total=50 } , {new DataPoint.Item() {name="Buccaneers", total=16 } }}}
};
```

I want to convert that first list into a list of ChartSeries that would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<ChartSeries> series = new List<ChartSeries>() {
        new ChartSeries() { Name = "Pirates", Values = new List<uint>() { 90, 80, 70, 60, 50} },
        new ChartSeries() { Name = "Buccaneers", Values = new List<uint>() { 20, 19, 18, 17, 16} },
};
```

How can I do this with Linq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested in LINQPad:

```
var q = from d in data
        from i in d.Items
        group i by i.name into g
        select new ChartSeries{
            Name = g.Key,
            Values = g.Select(i => (uint)i.total).ToList()
        };
```

Comment: +1, dam I fall in love with linq every-time I see a group-query like this ♥

Comment: Whoa, we are of one mind, my friend. I swear I posted without seeing your answer.

Comment: @subkamran: Actually, I believe you. The OP provided enough info to make LINQPad the obvious choice, and this really is the simplest (read best) solution. Stranger things have happened. :-)